# PHP array, print values in file one below another

Tags: php, line, break

```
file_put_contents($file, array_values($delivery[0]), FILE_APPEND);
```

That prints to file all values in the same row. How to print all values their own line?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implode the values into a string, separated by (in your case) a new line.

```
file_put_contents(
    $file,
    implode("\n", array_values($delivery[0])),
    FILE_APPEND
);
```